# React-Native - Unrecognized font family 'Ionicons'

Tags: react-native, react-native-vector-icons

my react version is over 0.6

1. i successfully install vector icons first `npm install react-native-vector-icons`
2. i did `npx pod-install` successfully
   (I don't use react-native link because it gives error and also when i check react-native > 0.6 there is autolinking usage so react-native link not preferable in react-native > 0.6)
3. Than i ran my app with this command

`npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 8"`

4. in my App.js file there is import like this. Also library shows no error !

> import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";

5. But when i want to use ionicons in JSX like this

> ```
> <Ionicons
>    name="information-circle-outline"
>    size={40}
>    color="blue"
> />
> ```

I got this error `Unrecognized font family 'Ionicons'`

than i ran `react-native link react-native-vector-icons`

also when i build by linking my build was failed. But when i unlink my build is successfull.

I don't understand where i make a mistake

[image]

Comment: Have you followed the installation instructions, including modifying your `Info.plist`? https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons

Comment: yes i tried. But not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since when you try to link it it fails. Try doing the linking manually.

Add this to your podfile in *ios/Podfile*

```
pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
```

then run `pod update` in the terminal and make sure your in the ios folder.

In addition you must follow there `Info.plist` instructions as well in there documentation.

Answer (score 1):

i have same question with u.
and just type `cd ios` and then `pod update` in the terminal
question solved

Comment: `npx pod-install` is doing a better job in the JavaScript ecosystem :)

https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/tree/main/packages/pod-install